# Installing imutils in windows 10 with python 3.6

Tags: python, window, anaconda

I need imutils package to run https://github.com/datitran/face2face-demo

The problem is installing it to my machine. I tried [`conda install -c mlgill imutils`](https://anaconda.org/mlgill/imutils) but runs into PackageNotFoundError
[image]

I also tried `pip install imutils` but another error came in. [image]

Can anyone share how you install imutils in windows 10 with Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install pip on anaconda platform 
use

1. *conda install pip*
   then use pip to install imutils
2. *pip install imutils*

The package will get installed.